# Sum Column in Table to variable

Tags: vba, ms-word, sum

I'm trying to sum up a column of a table in a word document. It's 3 column table, the length depends on the document. What I'm doing in the macro is the following:

I want to sum up the numbers in column 2. Then I'm adding some certain lines (headings in first column, no numbers in column 2) and change the order a bit. But I had the issue that sometimes lines get overwritten (due to bad programming...), so I want to sum up the second column in the end and compare the result with the one before (like a checksum).

How can I implement to sum up the values of the second table to a variable (not writing it into a cell), and compare it in the end?

```
Sub ModuleTest()

Dim numrows As Long
Dim col2 As Range

numrows = ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Rows.Count

Set col2 = ActiveDocument.Range( _
    Start:=ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Cell(1, 2).Range.Start, _
    End:=ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Cell(numrows, 2).Range.End)

'Code to sum up values in range col2

End Sub
```

I managed to define the range but now i want to sum it up to a variable.

Comment: You need to add your code (or at least the relevant parts) if you want help with it.

Comment: I have edited it. My problem is that I don't know how to save the sum to a variable. I have seen the codes with "Formula = sum(Above)" and so on but they always print the result

Comment: If your column 2 has no empty cells in the range to be summed and the header cell contains no numbers or dates, you could simply insert a formula field coded as {=SUM(ABOVE)} in the 'totals' row. If your code allows you to add/delete rows between the header row and the 'totals' row, you could simply have the field there all along and simply use ActiveDocument.Fields.Update to refresh it. To create such a field manually, simply press Ctrl-F9 to create a pair of field braces (i.e. {}), then type =SUM(ABOVE) between them and press F9 to update. Alternatively, you could insert the field with VBA.

Comment: Did my answer help you? If yes, please take a moment to mark it as the answer by clicking the checkmark to the left of it. This is helpful for the site.

Answer (score 1):

Good start and logical thinking - the only problem being that in Word a Range object must be contiguous (left-to-right, top-to-bottom). And the cells in a table column are not contiguous, so (unfortunately for us) cannot be assigned to a Range object.

That means you can either loop the Cell objects in a Column object *or* you can loop the Cells in a Selection object. The first is more correct from the object-oriented point of view; the second is faster in execution if there are a lot of cells.

Both approaches are in the code that follows. It tests whether the (truncated) cell content is numeric or not and sums those that are. (Why truncated: because the last characters of a Word cell are Chr(13) & Chr(7), which aren't numeric.)

```
Sub TableColumn()

'Working with Selection is faster
'    Dim tbl As word.Table
'    Dim runningSum As Double
'    Dim sel As word.Selection
'    Dim cel As word.Cell
'    Dim celContent As String
'
'    Set tbl = ActiveDocument.Tables(1)
'    runningSum = 0
'    tbl.Cell(1, 2).Select
'    Set sel = Selection
'    sel.Columns(1).Select
'
'    For Each cel In sel.Cells
'        celContent = Mid(cel.Range.Text, 1, Len(cel.Range.Text) - 1)
'        If IsNumeric(celContent) Then
'            runningSum = runningSum + CDbl(celContent)
'        End If
'    Next
'    Debug.Print runningSum

'Working with the pure object model is slower, but "cleaner"
    Dim tbl As word.Table
    Dim col As word.Column
    Dim runningSum As Double
    Dim cel As word.Cell
    Dim celContent As String

    Set tbl = ActiveDocument.Tables(1)
    Set col = tbl.Columns(2)
    runningSum = 0

    For Each cel In col.Cells
        celContent = Mid(cel.Range.Text, 1, Len(cel.Range.Text) - 1)
        If IsNumeric(celContent) Then
            runningSum = runningSum + CDbl(celContent)
        End If
    Next
    Debug.Print runningSum
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I managed to do it like this: I counted the amount of rows and went line by line with a for loop. to get the value as a number I used the `Val()` function. This is done before and after and then compared. It's simple but it works well :) 
    `Dim numrows As Integer
     Dim cellval As Double
     Dim columnsumbefore As Double

For i = 1 To numrows
    
        cellval = Val(tbl.Cell(i, 2).Range.Text)
        columnsumbefore = columnsumbefore + cellval
    
    Next i`